# How can I generate lotteries where I can simultaneously determine their expected values, variances and skewness?

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

First of all, thanks for taking the time to look at this. My goal is to be able to generate lotteries, where I can determine the first, second and third moments of their distributions, for a behavioural economics experiment. In other words, I'd like to be able to determine their expected values, variances and skewness.
\begin{align*}
 &\mathrm{Expected\ Value\ :} &&=\frac{\sum_{i}x_i}{n}\\
 &\mathrm{Variance:} &&=\frac{\sum_{i}(x_i-\mathrm{Mean})^2}{n}\\
 &\mathrm{Skewness:} &&=\sum_{i}\left( \frac{x_i-\mathrm{Mean}}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Variance}}}\right) ^3
\end{align*}
The lotteries will have three outcomes that are equally probable, so I believe this amounts to solving for $\{a,b,c\}$ in the following nonlinear system of equations, where $m, v$ and $s$ are just constants.
\begin{align}
 \frac{a+b+c}{3}= m\\
 \frac{
 (a-m)^2+(b-m)^2+(c-m)^2
 }{n}= v\\
 \frac{
 (a-m)^3+(b-m)^3+(c-m)^3
 }{\left( \sqrt{v}\right) ^3} = s
\end{align}
My questions is, how would you find for what values of $m,v$ and $s$ there are non-negative real solutions? I know that I can just input non-negative values for $a, b$ and $c$, but the issue with this is that, for my experiment, I would like to find triples of lotteries that satisfy one of the two following conditions. For three lotteries, say $\{1,2,3\}$, I would like either:

A. $\mathrm{Exp_1}=\mathrm{Exp_2}>\mathrm{Exp_3}$ and $\mathrm{Var_2}=\mathrm{Var_3}<\mathrm{Var_1}$ and $\mathrm{Skew_3}=\mathrm{Skew_1}<\mathrm{Skew_2}$
or
B. $\mathrm{Exp_1}=\mathrm{Exp_2}<\mathrm{Exp_3}$ and $\mathrm{Var_2}=\mathrm{Var_3}>\mathrm{Var_1}$ and $\mathrm{Skew_3}=\mathrm{Skew_1}>\mathrm{Skew_2}$

So, my question to you is, is this possible? And if so, how could I achieve it?

Many thanks and
best wishes,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Python code helps to find $a,b,c$ as a function of $m,v,s$ by transforming the set of equations `eqs1` that define mean, variance and skewness into an equivalent set of equations `eqs2` that is easy to solve.
In this case, it is enough to look at the last equation (which is printed by the code).

In the example I chose $m=v=s=1$ and the code produces the output
$$
a^3 - 3a^2 + \frac32a + \frac16
$$
which, by wolfram alpha, has the three solutions $-0.093199, 0.76963, 2.3236$.
By symmetry, the unique solution (up to swapping the values of $a,b,c$) is given by:
\begin{align*}
a &= -0.093199\\
b &=0.76963 \\
c &= 2.3236  
\end{align*}
Which means that you cannot realize $m=v=s=1$ if you want $a,b,c >0$.

---

```
from sympy import xring, QQ, lex
from sympy.polys import groebnertools as gt

P, variables= xring('c,b,a', QQ, lex)
c,b,a = variables

# choose your values for m,v,s below
m=1 # mean
v=1 # variance
s=1 # skewness

f1 = a+b+c - 3*m   
f2 = (a-m)**2 + (b-m)**2 + (c-m)**2 - 3*v  
f3 = (a-m)**3 + (b-m)**3 + (c-m)**3 - s*v**(3/2)

eqs1 = [f1,f2,f3]
eqs2 = gt.groebner(eqs1, P)

#for f in eqs2:
#    print(, "= 0")
print(eqs2[-1])
```

---

Read chapter 3.1 of [Cox Little O'Shea](http://people.dm.unipi.it/caboara/Misc/Cox,%20Little,%20O%27Shea%20-%20Ideals,%20varieties%20and%20algorithms.pdf) if you want to know why this works. Note that they refer to  `eqs2`  as a Gröbner basis for the Ideal generated by  `eqs1`.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it's more like a question on zeros of polynomials. It would be nice if someone provides a numerical perspective for it.
Your problem is equivalent to know if there are zeros for the following system of equation.
$$\begin{equation} a+b+c= u \\a^2+b^2+c^2= v \\ a^3+b^3+c^3= w\end{equation}$$
and that system is equivalent to:
$$\begin{equation} a+b+c= u=:x_1 \\ab+bc+ca= \dfrac{u^2-v}{2}=:x_2 \\ abc=\dfrac{2w+u^3-3uv}{6}=:x_3 \end{equation}$$

and this system of equations has three real roots( singular or not) , if the follow equation has three real roots.
$$X^3-x_1X^2+x_2X-x_3=0$$
Any further analysis that you want on $a,b,c$  can be translated to a study on the above equation.